# Loading the content before hide preloader

Tags: loading, onload, preloader

I am facing a problem with my preloader. The below is the url.

http://aceklouds.com/bimtec-wp/?page_id=9

In this preloader is not loading first. The content is loading first and then after fraction of seconds, preloader is coming. I am not able to solve this. Can anyone help me with this ??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have hidden the body before loading and then revealed it. Its working now.